# Watir: how to find iframe's tag?

Tags: watir

I have an element, for example `#<Watir::IFrame:0x..f98fef949215c673e located=false selector={:element=>(webdriver element)}>`. How do I determine what tag it is (iframe)?

Found it by searching for similar Javascript method: there exists `element.tag_name`, but when using it for **iframe** I get `NoMethodError: private method 'tag_name' called for #<Watir::IFrame:0x00000002f8c288>'`.

What does it mean and is there some alternative to `.tag_name` for **iframes**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception means that the `tag_name` method is private for Watir::IFrame (and Watir::Frame) objects. "Private", along with "public" and "protected", methods are used for controlling access of methods within a class. The [Ruby Pickaxe book](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html#S4) has a good description of the method types:

- Public methods can be called by anyone---there is no access control. Methods are public by default (except for initialize, which is always private).
- Protected methods can be invoked only by objects of the defining class and its subclasses. Access is kept within the family.
- Private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver. Because you cannot specify an object when using them, private methods can be called only in the defining class and by direct descendents within that same object.

Ultimately, this means that you cannot call the `tag_name` from outside of the class.

Given that the Watir API allows calling the `tag_name` method for other element types, I would say it is a bug. A pull request has been opened to have the method made public [Issue 293](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/pull/293).

As a workaround, you can call private methods by using `send`:

```
browser.iframe.send('tag_name')
#=> "iframe"
```

Note that given you already have a Watir::IFrame object and depending on what you are trying to do, you might not need to check the tag name. You could check the class of the object instead:

```
browser.iframe.class
#=> Watir::IFrame
```